I can't overlay density plots (from a spatstat hyperframe) with the respective contours
I am a cell biologist and I work with replicated point data. Therefore, I pooled the ppp's in a listof. I created density plots (with the generic plot tool) and contours, and I can plot both as lists (density.splitppp and contour.listof), so, they are all next to each other. but what I can't do, is combining the two by employing add = TRUE.
My FIRST naive attempt was to combine them like that:
combined_condition1 <- listof(res_condition1[[1]], res_condition1[[2]], res_condition1[[3]], res_condition1[[4]], res_condition1[[5]], res_condition1[[6]], res_condition1[[7]], res_condition1[[8]])

my_colourmap <- colourmap(plasma(256), range = c(0,0.004))
dens <- density.splitppp(combined_condition1, bw.diggle, positive=TRUE)
plot(dens, col = my_colourmap)
contour(dens, add = T)

This gives the following error code:
Error in extraplot(i, xi, ..., add = !is.null(panel.begin), main = main.panel[i],  : 
  formal argument "add" matched by multiple actual arguments

This makes total sense, as the add argument is just not part of density.splitppp and contour.listof.
So, I dug a little deeper, and found a great spatstat Vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/vignettes/replicated.pdf
In there, I found that you should put your lists in a hyperframe, and then pull up whatever you want from within the hyperframe to add it using quote(). So I changed my code:
combined_condition1 <- listof(res_condition1[[1]], res_condition1[[2]], res_condition1[[3]], res_condition1[[4]], res_condition1[[5]], res_condition1[[6]], res_condition1[[7]], res_condition1[[8]])
#I know, it's not elegant, but I am a beginner and I hate navigating in lists ;)

my_colourmap <- colourmap(plasma(256), range = c(0,0.004))
dens <- density.splitppp(combined_condition1, bw.diggle, positive=TRUE)

hyp <- hyperframe(Dicht=dens)

plot(hyp)
#... DOES WORK, BUT ONLY DENSITY

contour(hyp$Dicht)
#... DOES WORK, BUT ONLY CONTOUR

plot(hyp, col = my_colourmap, quote(contour(Dicht, add = TRUE)))
#... EMPTY GRAPH WINDOW THAT JUST SAYS "hyp"

I think, now it should work, and I have no idea why id doesnt. In the vignette they show this as an example, which I think is basically the same thing:
# Note the use of quote, which prevents the code inside the braces from being evaluated immediately.
# To plot the K-functions of each of the patterns in the waterstriders dataset,

> H <- hyperframe(Bugs=waterstriders)
> plot(H, quote(plot(Kest(Bugs))), marsize=1)

AND
> plot(demohyper, quote({ plot(Image, main=""); plot(Points, add=TRUE) }))

I updated EVERYTHING, because I thought it might be a problem with the Graph viewer/the R Studio Version, but I couldn't find any solution. My girlfriend suggested photoshop ;)
Thank you!

Literally minutes later I found the solution :D  hyp2 <- hyperframe(com = combined_condition1) plot(hyp2, quote({plot(density(com)); contour(density(com), add = T)}))

There are several ways to do this in spatstat.

For your particular problem: plot.im has an argument addcontour. If X is a pixel image object, then plot(X, addcontour=TRUE) will draw X as a colour image and then overlay contour lines. You can control the colour and spacing of the contours with contourargs.

The layered class is designed to represent multiple graphics layers superimposed on one another, similar to "a photo editing package". Each layer can have its own list of plot arguments. To display a pixel image X in colour and then superimpose contour lines in white, you could do
L <- layered(X, X, plotargs=list(list(), list(.plot="contour", col="white")))
and then just plot(L). The first layer is the image X with no plot parameters, so plot(X) is executed, which gives the colour image. The second layer is X again: the special parameter .plot specifies the function that does the plotting, and in this case it indicates that the second layer should be plotted by the contour function, so contour(X, add=TRUE, col="white") is executed.
Advantages of layered objects are that you can easily select/deselect different layers; the plot command plot.layered always creates enough plot space to display all the layers; and the spatial positions of the layers are correctly aligned.

If the objects are organised in a hyperframe then you can use plot.hyperframe to do any desired sequence of plot commands on each row of the hyperframe, plot(h, quote(............))


